# Reading Content property of a Button into a ConrtolTemplate in a style

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a style for a button with a ControlTemplate something like this

```
 <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"
               BasedOn="{x:Null}"
               TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle"
                               Fill="#FF04822A"
                               Stroke="{x:Null}" />
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               FontWeight="Heavy"
                               Foreground="Black"
                               x:Name="btnText"
                               TextAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

```xml
  <Button Grid.Row="3"
                Grid.Column="5"
                Margin="4,0,4,0"
                Command="{Binding ResetCommand}"
                Content ="Reset Cells"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
```

I want the TextBlock   to read from the button Content every time its updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a template binding to the `TextBlock`:

```
Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
```

You might just want to use a `ContentPresenter` instead though (as `TextBlocks` usually only display text).